# Update and Delete are not batched in Spring Boot and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm trying to get my Spring boot application to work with batching mode for the create update and delete operations.
I have succeeded to do the creation operation with the following articles:

1. https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-multi-row-insert-rewritebatchedinserts-property/
2. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update

At my application level, with the help of the proxy data source, I could see that the batching is working for all my operations, it looks like this:

```
[-exec-6] SLF4JQueryLoggingListener:20 - {"name":"Batch-Insert-Logger", "connection":33, "time":9, "success":true, "type":"Prepared", "batch":true, "querySize":1, "batchSize":5, "query":["
```

At the PostgreSQL level, I could see that the insertion works after I configured the reWriteBatchedInserts=true in my DB connection.
I verified it with the actual PostgreSQL logs.

However, for the update and delete operations, I can still see in the logs that it is not batched in the PostgreSQL level.
Is there any additional configuration that I need to do in order to get this done?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to use batching for inserts/updates, we should be aware of the primary key generation strategy. If our entities use GenerationType.IDENTITY identifier generator, Hibernate will silently disable batch inserts/updates.

Please use sequence instead...

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;
```

Source: [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update)

Comment: I'm using sequence like described in the article.
Notice that my problem is not on the Hibernate level